# Casting and Argument Warnings

Tags: c++, c, unix, pthreads

I have the following code, compiles and executes without errors but the compiler shows some warnings that I would like to "solve".

Thats my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct s_Barrier{
    sem_t sEntry, sMutEx, sExit;
    int nTaskInBarrier;
}Barrier;

void createTasks(pthread_t threads[]);
void task(void *arg);
void initBarrier(Barrier *pb, int n);
void destroyBarrier(Barrier *pb);
void waitInBarrier(Barrier *pb);


Barrier barrier;
int nTask = 5;


int main(void) {
    pthread_t threads[nTask];

    initBarrier(&barrier,nTask);
    createTasks(threads);
    destroyBarrier(&barrier);

    return 0;
}

void createTasks(pthread_t threads[]){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < nTask; i++){
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, task, (void*)i);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < nTask; i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }
}

void initBarrier(Barrier *pb, int n){
    pb->nTaskInBarrier = 0;

    sem_init(&pb->sEntry,0,n);
    sem_init(&pb->sExit,0,1);
    sem_init(&pb->sMutEx,0,1);
}

void destroyBarrier(Barrier *pb){
    sem_destroy(&pb->sEntry);
    sem_destroy(&pb->sExit);
    sem_destroy(&pb->sMutEx);
}

void task(void *arg){
    int i = (int) arg;
    while(1){
        printf("I'm thread %d\n",i);
        waitInBarrier(&barrier);
    }
}

void waitInBarrier(Barrier *pb){
    int x;
    int i;

    sem_wait(&pb->sEntry);
    sem_wait(&pb->sMutEx);

    x = ++pb->nTaskInBarrier;

    sem_post(&pb->sMutEx);

    if(x < nTask){
        sem_wait(&pb->sExit);
    }else{
        for(i = 0; x < nTask ; i++){
            sem_post(&pb->sExit);
        }
    }

    sem_wait(&pb->sMutEx);

    x = --pb->nTaskInBarrier;

    sem_post(&pb->sMutEx);

    if(x == 0){
        for(i = 0; x < nTask ; i++){
            sem_post(&pb->sEntry);
        }
    }

}
```

When I compile using the "gcc -o Barrier 3.4Barrier.c -pthread" get the following Warnings.

```
3.4Barrier.c: In function ‘createTasks’:
3.4Barrier.c:47:43: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, task, (void*)i);
                                       ^
    3.4Barrier.c:47:37: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, task, (void*)i);
                                 ^
In file included from 3.4Barrier.c:13:0:
/usr/include/pthread.h:233:12: note: expected ‘void * (*)(void *)’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(void *)’
 extern int pthread_create (pthread_t *__restrict __newthread,
        ^
    3.4Barrier.c: In function ‘task’:
    3.4Barrier.c:70:10: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size     [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  int i = (int) arg;
```

Comment: put an ampersand before task: pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, &task, (void*)i);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that `task` should return `void*`, not `void`, as specified by the prototype of [`pthread_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

```
void* task(void *arg) {
    // ...
    return NULL;
}
```

This is easily solved.

The second problem is that you should not pass `i` this way - You should not cast an `int` to a `void*`. One way to pass `i` to `task` would be to allocate a small space of memory and use it<sup>1</sup>:

```
for(i = 0; i < nTask; i++){
    int *pi = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (pi == NULL) { 
        // Something wrong...
    }
    *pi = i;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, task, pi);
}
```

And:

```
void* task(void *arg){
    int i = *(int*)arg; // Cast to `int*` and then dereference.
    free(arg); // Don't forget this!
    while(1){
        printf("I'm thread %d\n",i);
        waitInBarrier(&barrier);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> Do not try to pass `(void*)&i` directly to `pthread_create` because there is no guarantee that `*(int*)arg` will be evaluated before the increment in the `for` loop so you might get some weird behavior where `i` is changed before you read its value.</sub>

Comment: Solved all warnings! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
void createTasks(pthread_t threads[]){
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < nTask; i++){
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, task, (void*)i);
  }
```

to:

```
void createTasks(pthread_t threads[]){
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < nTask; i++){
      int *arg = malloc(Sizeof(int));
      *arg = i;
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, task, (void*)arg);
  }
```

Then change:

```
void task(void *arg){
    int i = (int) arg;
    while(1){
        printf("I'm thread %d\n",i);
        waitInBarrier(&barrier);
    }
}
```

to

```
void *task(void *arg){
    int i = *((int *) arg);
    free(arg);
    while(1){
        printf("I'm thread %d\n",i);
        waitInBarrier(&barrier);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will avoid the errors that you have encountered as it gets over the problem of void and ints being different sizes.

Also it will give the write return type for task

Answer (score 0):

make some changes :
1- `void *task(void *arg);` in line 13 and in line 59
because task is used as pointer to function in `pthread_create` function

> int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
>       void *(*start_routine)(void*), void *arg);

2- `int i = *((int *)arg);` in line 60
3- compile like this gcc Barrier.c -lpthread